# What are the consequences of using contentEditable on a textarea?

Tags: html, contenteditable

As you can see, at least on Chrome, the `contentEditable` attribute seems to be ignored on `textarea`.

Question A: Is that how it's supposed to work?

Question C: Does using `contentEditable` on a `textarea` have any consequences other than proving you're an idiot?

Question D: Why is there no question B? *Just kidding, I had a clown for breakfast today. :D*

```css
textarea { /* not relevant for the question, only for the demo */
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<textarea contentEditable="true">contentEditable="true"</textarea>
<textarea contentEditable="false">contentEditable="false"</textarea>
<textarea contentEditable="true" readonly>contentEditable="true" readonly</textarea>
<textarea contentEditable="true" disabled>contentEditable="true" disabled</textarea>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

`contentEditable` has no effect and on textarea, [the HTML5 spec is mute about the subject](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-contenteditable).

`contentEditable=false` allows to make an element *not editable* inside another element which is `contentEditable=true`. The default behavior is to `inherit` the value of `contentEditable` so that every children of an editable element is also editable.

You can still delete the non-editable element but not edit it. This is demonstrated in the following snippet.

```css
textarea { /* not relevant for the question, only for the demo */
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">
    <span>Editable span</span> but
    <span contentEditable="false">This one is not</span>
</textarea>
```